# JS / React - Function returns undefined before finished

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

In my React application I have created a function to get a particular image size from an array which contains data about the image such as mimetype, available sizes, paths, etc.

```
export default function getImageSize(image, size) {

    // Map through each available size for the image
    image.sizes.forEach((v, i) => {

        // Return the fullpath if there is a match for the requested size
        if (v.type === size) {
           return v.fullpath;
        }

    });

}
```

I am calling this function with:

```
let smallImageSize = getImageSize(data.images[0], 'small');
```

And using it in my page with:

```
<img alt="thumbnail" src={smallImageSize} />
```

As you can probably guess (for the more experienced), my function returns undefined as the loop inside the function has not returned before the function is finished.

My question is, how can I ensure that my function will WAIT for a return value before anything else within my render function continues? Is using a promise the only way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Also I just had an idea: Would it be a better idea to use this function and load the URL through state before the page renders in componentWillMount? I am running this function within my render() in React.

Comment: You should use `const foundSize = image.sizes.find(imageSize => imageSize.type === size); return foundSize && foundSize.fullpath;` instead of the forEach.

Comment: Also, we need to know what `data.images[0]` is.

Comment: Actually, the function `getImageSize` returns `undefined` once the whole thing is finished, so the title is misconceived - and `es6-promise` tag is unwarranted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue lies in your `forEach` loop. Returning a value from a forEach loop does not actually do anything.

You need to use `find` instead:

```
export default function getImageSize(image, size) {

    // Map through each available size for the image
    const img = image.sizes.find(v => {

        // Return the image if there is a match for the requested size
        if (v.type === size) {
           return true;
        }

    });

    // img can be undefined if it does not exist
    return img && img.fullpath;
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer, thanks so much for helping. That is the way to do it! I will have add find() to my Javascript arsenal and use this in the future. Cheers.